# Using Q library for HTTP api response testing in nodejs

Tags: node.js, q, synchronous

how to use Q to make it wait until previous response has come from the server.
What I am looking to do here is compare the response from test server and production server for the same request.

I get the responses back from both the servers, but unable to compare them since the assert statement is executed before the response comes back.

Any one know what I am doing wrong. heres the code.

```
    var Q = require('q');

    var path='';
    var prodResponse = '';
    var tstReponse = '';

    Q.fcall(readFile())
      .then(secondFunction())
      .then(thirdFunction())
      .then(function(){
          console.log("prodResponse: "+prodResponse);
          console.log("tstResponse: "+tstResponse);
          assert.strictEqual(prodResponse, tstResponse)
      })
      .catch(function(){
        console.log('error occurred');
      })
      .done();

    function readFile(){
      fs.readFile('hostname.json', function (err, data) {
        if (err) return  console.error(err);
          path = JSON.parse(data);
return JSON.parse(data);
        });
    }

    function secondFunction(){
      var prodOptions = {
        hostname: 'somehostname.com',
        port: 80,
        path: "/path?"+path.path,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
        },
        auth : ''
      };

      return http.request(prodOptions, function(res) {
        console.log('Prod');    
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
          prodResponse = chunk;
          return chunk;
        });
        res.on('end', function() {
          console.log('No more data in response.');
        })
      }).on('error', function(e) {
        console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
      }).end();
    }

    function thirdFunction(){
    // same a second, only difference is the response http. 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is multiple errors in your code

```
Q.fcall(readFile())
```

Your `q` variable is `q` and not `Q`. So this line will crash because `Q` is undefined (javascript is case sensitive).

Then, `readFile` doesn't return any promise (in fact, it returns nothing). So the `q` library can't use anything to wait the end of any asynchronous work. The `then` callbacks will be fired immediatly.

Comment: those were typos, yet again I recheck and made edits, but there still seems to be a problem. let me see if I can create a example on jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Q.ninvoke` to make your `readFile` function return a promise, and you can use `Q.defer` to create and return a promise from your `secondFunction`:

```
var Q = require('q');

var path='';
var prodResponse = [];
var tstReponse = '';

readFile()
  .then(secondFunction())
  .then(thirdFunction())
  .then(function(){
      console.log("prodResponse: "+prodResponse);
      console.log("tstResponse: "+tstResponse);
      assert.strictEqual(prodResponse, tstResponse)
  })
  .catch(function(){
    console.log('error occurred');
  })
  .done();

function readFile(){
  return Q.ninvoke(fs, 'readFile', 'hostname.json').then(function (data) {
    path = JSON.parse(data);
    return path;
  }, function (err) {
    console.error(err);
  });
}

function secondFunction(){
  var prodOptions = {
    hostname: 'somehostname.com',
    port: 80,
    path: "/path?"+path.path,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
    },
    auth : ''
  };

  var defer = Q.defer();
  var chunks = [];

  http.request(prodOptions, function(res) {
    console.log('Prod');    
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
      chunks.push(chunk);
    });
    res.on('end', function() {
      console.log('No more data in response.');
      prodResponse = chunks.join('');
      defer.resolve(prodResponse);
    })
  }).on('error', function(e) {
    console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
    defer.reject(e);
  }).end();

  return defer.promise;
}

function thirdFunction(){
// same a second, only difference is the response http. 
}
```